# how do I parse this in PHP

Tags: xml, parsing

I am using simpleXML and get back the result like so:

SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [minorVersion] => 3 [majorVersion] => 3 [inferiorVersion] => 0 ) )

I would appreciate if I can get some help parsing this information - I have tried $xml(the oblect) like $xml->@attributes[minorVersion] but do not get anything back

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the nodes are objects. One thing you can do is call the attributes() method which returns you an array.  Make sure you always cast the result to an appropriate php type like (string), especially when doing comparisons.

```
$t = $xml->node->attributes();
echo (string) $t['minorVersion'];
```

You could also just try referencing it directly:

```
echo (string) $xml->node['minorVersion'];
```

Comment: Thanks - I got it to work, however, it needed to be accessed without the node - E.g: 
$t = $xml->attributes();

Comment: A question though - would the methods always be represented as @method_name?

Comment: Glad you got it to work... could you accept this as your answer then?  Yes the @ in that readout is indicating it's a method in the datastructure vs a variable.